# Wait for TextField input, before continuing with the code

Tags: java

I have a Graphical User Interface that has a `TextField`, my code looks as following:

```
int port = 0;
    try{
    port = Integer.parseInt(frame.textfieldInput.getText());
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException npe)
    {
        System.out.println("Error! parse exception");
    }

    System.out.println("The Port is " + port); //is 0
```

I have to assign the value '0' to port, because otherwise the code wont compile, because the variable wouldn't be initialized.

Because the `TextField` is empty at the beginning of the Program, `getText()` wont get a value, which is why port stays '0'.

Is there any way to wait for the input before the code continues?

Comment: You can put the code into a listener which operates on changes of the textfield or on button clicks etc. Alternatively call a modal dialog (`JOptionPane`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, this is how I solved it:

I created a global variable outside of my `ActionListener`:

```
public String value = "";
public void createInput() {
    buttonInput.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            value = textfieldInput.getText();

        }

    });
}
```

named 'value'.

in my `public static void main(String[] args)` I declared the following:

```
while(frame.value.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
{
    try
    {
        System.out.println("waiting...");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    catch(InterruptedException ie)
    {
    System.out.println("interrupted");
    }
}
```

I just have to clear the variable 'value' everytime I used it, so it is empty again for future uses.

I tis not the best way to solve it, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Below code may give you some idea to more efficient way to get value on focus lost.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setSize(50, 50);
TextField field = new TextField();
field.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
        // continue from here
        System.out.println(field.getText());
    }

    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
frame.getContentPane().add(field);
frame.setVisible(true);
```